# Allow textbox only digits and first digit starts with 2 to9

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My regular expression to allow only digits in textbox is /[^\d]/g. But the first digit should be within 2-9 and remaining digits from 0-9. I tried with 
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/. its not working.

Comment: But this pattern `/[^\d]/g` explicitly prevents digits...? And if you want to match 2-9 in the first digit, shouldn't the pattern be `/^[2-9][0-9]*$/`?

Comment: Actually it should be `/^[2-9][0-9]*$/` if you want it to start from 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow at least 2 digits satisfying your condition, try this `/(^[2-9][0-9]{1,}$)/`

Answer (score 0):

Use `/^[2-9][0-9]*$/`

Demo:

```js
var re = /^[2-9][0-9]*$/

// Invalid inputs
console.log(re.test("100"));
console.log(re.test("01"));

// Valid inputs
console.log(re.test("2017"));
console.log(re.test("2"));
```